How to hide clutter in Python debugger on-hover in VSCode?
I happen to be using Cursor, but the question is the same for VSCode and Windsurf.
Consider
        import numpy as np
        class A:
            static_var = 0
            def __call__(self):
                return 0
            def __init__(self) -> None:
                self.public = 0
                self._protected = 1
                self.__private = 2
                self.arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
            def foo():
                return 0
            @staticmethod
            def bar():
                return 0
        a = A()

and hover on a.

Is there a way to configure the hover window and watch window to not show any of

special variables
-- __call__ is overriden but now opening special_variables shows all magic methods, not just the one overriden.
-- better not to see any of it anyway.
function variables (the object's functions)
protected variables (start with _)
private variables (start with __ in code but start with classname_ in actual object)
hide the ability to go into structures outside my own code (such as the inner structure of numpy arrays)?

Is there a way to change the order in which the options are are shown to have the less relevant stuff at the bottom at least?

This doesn't happen in Pycharm. There, by default, functions are not shown in objects (not static nor bound methods not class methods nor magic functions); private variables are hidden by default. Stepping into external code is possible but somehow feels like it doesn't pollute the entire screen.
I don't have PyCharm installed right now to show exactly the same code, but there it's clean. You see "what you actually want to" and have a way to see the rest if you realy need to.

How to get rid of the clutter in VScode?

